# How to redirect my own domain to notion.so page via aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have my own domain registered by amazon. I also have a route53 hosted zone for that domain.
I want to redirect all the incoming requests to notion.so page. (https and HTTP)

How can I do that in was.

For reference cloudflare solution can be found on this link
https://medium.com/@TarasPyoneer/how-to-set-up-a-custom-domain-for-your-homepage-in-notion-53fa3d54f848

Answer (score 0):

Follow the guide here:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-domain-route-53/

For https, you maybe want to look into cloudfront (out of the box if you follow the steps above you will only get http) :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-https.html

Last link (it shows everything e2e by walking through the console):
https://dev.to/marklocklear/redirecting-a-domain-with-https-using-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront-526h

Answer (score -1):

if "notion.so" is your domain .

**Add Record Type "A"** , and **add your server Ec2 Instance's Public IP** Address or EIP as its value Ex, "192.198.0.1"

and **add another record named "CNAME"** with value **"www.notion.so"**